# C# recursive statement in calculator error

Tags: c#, recursion, calculator

I've created a simple calculator previously, and now I'm trying to improve it with a bit more error handling built in. I'm trying to call a function to read an int, tryparsing, and if it fails to re-call the function until `TryParse()` is successful.

My issue is that the false path does not return a value so it will not compile. I'm sure there is a simple step I am missing, can anyone help me with some advice? Can this problem be fixed within `GetNumber()`? Or should I call the function conditionally within `Main()`? Anything else?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static int GetNumber()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        string entry = Console.ReadLine();

        int num;

        bool res = int.TryParse(entry, out num);

        if (res == true)
        {
            return num;
        }

        if (res == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a proper number");
            GetNumber();
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int x = GetNumber();
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursion doesn't help here, all you need is a loop that exits when a valid number is entered. (There is nothing about the previous failures that you care about. Recursion is happily piling them up on the call stack.) Aside: A couple of options for an unhappy function exiting are: (A) Make it return a nullable type, e.g. `int?`, and return `null` if there is no valid input. That complicates things for the caller, but so it goes. (2) Use `throw` to report an appropriate exception to the caller. They'll get the message.

Comment: Regarding the `if` statements: Typically `if (res)` would suffice for testing a `boolean` for truth. There is no need for checking in depth, e.g. `(res == true)` or ( ( res == true ) == true )`. And in many cases the other value of a `boolean` is `false` and easily handled with an `else` clause rather than an independent `if` statement.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback! I have a question about your statement HABO about not needing recursion. If I were to include recursion, would it be possible to cause problems to my program by repeatedly entering non-integer (failing) statements and having the stack eventually have too many things pile up on it? For example, if someone were to feed it a never-ending loop of a letter or word.

Comment: Yes, additional stack space is needed for each level of recursion. In this case it may not be a realistic problem, i.e. you aren't allocating much memory for each recursion and a creature would likely tire of entering bad data after a few thousand attempts. Recursion is useful when you need to preserve an existing _state_, e.g. pieces on a chess board while you try making moves that may not work well. You can simply back up a few steps and return to an earlier state. Some problems can be solved neatly by either looping or recursion, e.g. calculating the factorial of a number.

Answer (score 1):

Add a return before your recursive `GetNumber`. This will return the recursed value back up the chain before ultimately returning back to your `Main` method.

You can remove the second `if` statement entirly, since you'll only be there if `res` is false. This doesn't impact the functionality, just makes it a little easier to read.

```
static int GetNumber(){
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
    string entry = Console.ReadLine();
    int num;
    bool res = int.TryParse(entry, out num);
    if (res == true){
        return num;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a proper number");
    return GetNumber();        
}
```